# Access an axios data formatted as json from vue

Tags: json, vue.js, flask, axios, response

I need to show data from a json response from get request. Vue part of my code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app2',
      delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
      data: {
        masa_data: {},
      },
      mounted: function() {

              polling1=setInterval(function() {
              axios.get('/order')
                  .then(function(response) {
                      vm.$data.masa_data = response.data;
                  })
          }, 1000);        
      },

      beforeDestroy () {
        clearInterval(this.polling1)
      }
  });
</script>
```

masa_data comes from axios as below:

> { "Bahçe1": { "A": { "1": { "kisi_sayisi": "2", "siparisler": [ {
>   "adet": 2, "bolum": "drink", "satir": "Açık Çay" }, { "adet": 1,
>   "bolum": "tatli", "satir": "Kaymaklı Ekmek Kadayıfı" } ] },

When i want to show, for example, value of "kisi_sayisi", I could not figure out what to put inside html code below:

```
<p class="card-text">[[masa_data]]</p>
```

Comment: You can directly use ['key_name'] right?

Comment: Say masa_data['Bahçe1']['A']['1']['kisi_sayisi']

Comment: normally yes. I tried that. But view did not show up with that.

Comment: maybe because of  [[..]] braces?

Comment: It's possible if data is not present try V-if <span v-if="Object.Values(masa_data).length>0">masa_data['Bahçe1']['A']['1']['kisi_sayisi']</span>

Comment: " <p class="card-text">[[masa_data]]</p> " shows view with whole data. but whenever i put something like  " <p class="card-text">[[masa_data['Bahçe1']['A']['1']['kisi_sayisi']]]</p> " , view doesnt show up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<p class="card-text" v-if="Object.values(masa_data).length>0">[[masa_data.Bahce1.A['1']['kisi_sayisi'] ]]</p>
```

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/QWbjOxE?editors=1010